# What is more correct $2^{A}$ or $2^{|A|}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I saw at mt notebook this: for any set $A$: $$|A|\le |2^{A}|$$
Now I'm wondering, what is the meaning of $2^A$? $A$ is not a number...

It doesn't need to be: $$|A|\le |2^{|A|}|$$ or $$|A|\le 2^{|A|}$$?

Thank you!

Comment: $2^A$ is the set of functions from $A$ to $2=\{0,1\}$. The inequality $|A|\leqslant|2^A|$ states (correctly) that there exists an injection from $A$ to $2^A$.

Comment: $2^A$ is the power set of $A$, which is the collection of every subsets of $A$, it is denoted as $2^A$ because it has $2^{|A|}$ elements

Comment: @Bubububu "it is denoted as $2^A$ because it has $2^{|A|}$ elements" Actually there are much stronger reasons to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In set theory, $2$ formally means $\{0, 1\}$ (or $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$ to be precise), so $2^A$ is just the set of all functions with domain $A$ and range $2$.

$|2^A|$ denotes the cardinality (size) of this set and that's how you define powers of cardinal numbers:
$|A|^{|B|} := |A^B|$.

Comment: I'll add that $|A^B| = |A^{|B|}|$ is also true since you should interpret $A^{|B|}$ as the set of function from the cardinal $|B|$ (which is a set) to $A$.